# Different output for IE and the rest

Tags: html, css

For some reason this class outputs ok in IE but in Firefox the words and the lines ( | ) are not centered:

```
.horz_list li {
    display: inline; 
    background-color: #CEE3F8;  
    border-right-style:thin; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
    padding-left: 4px;  
}
```

This is the page for the output:

```
<div id="top_nav">
  <ul class="horz_list">
    <li><a href="<?php echo APP_DIR.'index.php?action=newest'; ?>">Nuevas</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo APP_DIR.'index.php?action=comments&param=new'; ?>">Comentarios</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="<?php echo APP_DIR.'index.php?action=submit'; ?>">Enviar</a></li>
  </ul> <!-- ul.horz_list -->
</div> <!-- top_nav -->
```

If anyone know why is this, thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or link?

Comment: By the way, <?= $var ?> is equivalent to (and shorter than) <? echo $var; ?>

Comment: @cletus: I'm pretty sure <?= only works with short tags enabled, and for maximum portability I always use <?php echo $var ?>

Comment: Yeah it is the short tags thing.  Can't say I've ever seen it not enabled though.

Comment: I havn't either... but you never know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the li's properties

```
.horz_list li{
    display: block; /* block level */
    float: left;  /* float them inline to the left */
    overflow: hidden; /* this will force the div to stretch to it's contained element */
    background-color: #CEE3F8;  
    border-right-style:thin; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
    padding-left: 4px;  
}
```

... or if you want what [Ben described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592946/different-output-for-ie-and-the-rest/593004#593004), the whole block centred, use

```
.horz_list {
   margin: 0 auto;


}
```

Ensure it's containing block has a width, even if it's 100%.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get your list items to be horizontally centered, this is accomplished differently in IE vs. other browsers.  Try setting `margin-left:auto;margin-right;auto` on your `<ul>`:

```
.horz_list {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason for the extra spacing in Firefox is that if you set the LI as display:inline, the newline in your HTML code creates an extra space (just like if you type "lorem(newline)ipsum" the words may appear side to side in the page with a space between them).

Try, for example, to stick the <LI> tags together like this <li>....</li><li>.... and I think this will remove the unwanted spaces.

If you don't like to put it all into a single line, alex's suggestion works, but you may have to add a <div style="clear:both"></div> after the closing UL, because of floated elements.

Comment: You could also set the div's overflow: hidden to accomplish this without any unnecessary markup.